# Android app is freezing when MQTT event occurred

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When the application is open and MQTT event-triggered then I am facing this error. I am tried to reopen the activity but the activity is not found and I not able to understand How the activity is lost and how to resolve this error.

```
Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=driver.RIDER_NEW_TRIP_REQUEST flg=0x10 (has extras) } in driver.base.home.presentation.HomeActivity$4@ecbe5e6 
 at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1656) 
 at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment GiveRideFragment{77827c8} not attached to a context. 
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:696) 
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:760) 
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getString(Fragment.java:782) 
 at driver.feature.giveRide.presentation.GiveRideFragment.display(GiveRideFragment.java:2763) 
 at driver.shared.datastore.DriverRequestQueue.poll(DriverRequestQueue.java:65) 
 at driver.feature.giveRide.presentation.GiveRideFragment.fetchCurrentTripData(GiveRideFragment.java:910) 
 at driver.feature.giveRide.presentation.GiveRideFragment.makeAPICalls(GiveRideFragment.java:833) 
 at driver.base.home.presentation.HomeActivity$4.onReceive(HomeActivity.java:625)



if (intent != null) {
                    Log.e("MQTT received :", "YES");
                    Log.e("MQTT received sound : ", "YES");

                    RiderNewTripRequest riderNewTripRequest = (RiderNewTripRequest) intent.
                            getSerializableExtra(Constants.IntentKey.RiderNewTripRequest);

                    Log.e("MQTT receivedrequest: ", "YES");
                    if (riderNewTripRequest != null) {

                        binding.navDrawer.itemNavGiveRide.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(
                                HomeActivity.this, R.color.colorHighlight));
                        closeDrawers();
                        Fragment frg = null;
                        frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
                        final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        assert frg != null;
                        ft.detach(frg);
                        ft.attach(frg);
                        ft.commit();
                        if (currentFrag() instanceof GiveRideFragment) {
                            Log.e("MQTT requestttttt ", "YES");
                            giveRideFragment.makeAPICalls(riderNewTripRequest);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I have update code.

Comment: I can't see your code here

Comment: There is nothing from the MQTT library in the stack trace, so removing the tag. Also you REALLY need to show the code to go with this stack trace.